# Multiple file upload using NodeJS or HTML5

Tags: node.js, html

I have a project with bulk upload of files. Currently it is done by draging and droping of a bunch of files into a HTML5 uploader and as it goes through the web server it takes time to process all the files to upload, at the same time a windows application that don't use server is much quicker. Currently we are going to discontinue the windows application for some reason.

My question is does NodeJS process the files through WEB SERVER or does it works in asynchronous way by using network path to upload without using web server?

OR

Does it works similarly to that of HTML5 Uploader through IIS Server?

Is there any other way to avoid the files going through web server just in case if the application is running local network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your question, but this is my method to multiple upload file:

Nodejs :

```
router.post('/upload', function(req , res) {

var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var form = new multiparty.Form();
var fs = require('fs');

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {  
    var imgArray = files.imatges;


    for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        var newPath = './public/uploads/'+fields.imgName+'/';
        var singleImg = imgArray[i];
        newPath+= singleImg.originalFilename;
        readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath);           
    }
    res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);

});

function readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath) {

        fs.readFile(singleImg.path , function(err,data) {
            fs.writeFile(newPath,data, function(err) {
                if (err) console.log('ERRRRRR!! :'+err);
                console.log('Fitxer: '+singleImg.originalFilename +' - '+ newPath);
            })
        })
}
```

})

Make sure your has enctype="multipart/form-data"

I hope this gives you a hand ;)